# Adding custom view in random (x,y) positions inside another custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a custom view consisting of imageview and textview. Lets call it CustomViewA. I would like to add several instances of this view to another custom view (CustomViewB) in random positions like so:[image]

How can I say in CustomViewB, something like canvas.drawLayout(new CustomViewA(text, imageBackground), x,y)??? I.e. draw CustomViewA in specific (x,y) position inside CustomViewB?And then manipulate this CustomViewA like I would any Shape on touching,dragging, etc? If I would make CustomViewB custom Layout how can I overwrite onLayout(), onMeasure(), taking into account that CustomViewA-s don't relate to each other in any way?

Comment: in container view all you need is to implement ViewGroup.onLayout method,  thats all

Comment: thanks. how do I add the custom view into container view?

Comment: ViewGroup.addView(), read ViewGroup docs